# Вопрос про сохранение данных, живущих в рамках процесса

Tags: android, архитектура

У меня есть данные которые должны переживать перевороты и смерть процесса.

Сейчас у меня сделано хранение данных в презентере. И в презентер добавил методы `saveInstanceState(bundle state)` и `restoreInstanceState(Bundle state)`. Эти методы презентера просто вызываются фрагментом в `onSaveInstanceState` и в `onCreate` соответственно.

Но это плохо, потому что таким образом презентер знает про андроид сдк классы и не представляется возможным тестировать его юнит тестами. Ну только если мокать bundle.
Мне предлагали решение обернуть данные в pojo класс, т.е. чтобы презентер возвращал pojo класс, который скажем Serializable и фрагмент дергал этот метод презентера, получал этот pojo класс и уже сохранял его в бандл. Но таким образом получается вью(фрагмент) не очень то пассивная.

Может кто-то уже решал подобную проблему и знает лучшее решение?

Answer (score 2):

В целом подход вам рекомендовали верный, но правильнее так:

1) при поворотах презентер не должен умирать, так как это чисто особенность андроида - умирающая вьюха

2) для восстановления после смерти процесса надо сделать следующее
 - вынести такие данные в Pojo модельку.
 - в модельке сделать два метода `saveToBundle(bundle)` и `restoreFromBundle(bundle)`
 - инжектить ее в классы где она нужна, а также в класс Активити
 - в активити сохранять и восстанавливать данные после смерти процесса

Таким образом Активити будет играть роль системного компонента с задачей восстановления данных после смерти процесса.

Но важно помнить, что обычно сохранение в бандл - это крайняя мера. Все необходимые данные должны быть в БД или другом хранилище.